# Java Scanner that takes only letters and spaces, but not space-only strings

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I've done a simple program that allows user to enter a name and then greets him.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class nameinput {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a name: (only letters, at least 2 characters long)");
        while (true) {
            String name= sc.next();
            if (name.length() < 2){
                System.out.println("This name is too short!");
                continue;
            }
            else if (!name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
                System.out.println("Letters only!");
                continue;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Hello, " + name);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I have two issues I can't solve:

1. When user inputs a name containing a space, it only gets what's before space.
2. When user passes only a series of spaces, or doesn't pass anything, nothing happens, like he didn't type anything. I'd the user to receive a proper message informing him that the spaces-only strings and empty strings are not allowed.

I hope I was clear in descriptions of problems, thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Does `Scanner` have a delimiter? What is it by default?

Comment: You need to use nextLine() in order to get Scanner inputs that contains white space(more than 1 word) //String name= sc.nextLine();

Answer (score 4):

If you just replace `sc.next` with `sc.nextLine()`. nextLine will capture all the key press until press enter.

Comment: `sc.next()` reads the next word. if you only have spaces or newlines these will be consumed until it gets to the next word +1

Comment: Thanks! That helped, but also generated another issue:
When user types a name containing a space, space is treated like a non-letter. To what should I change the  `!name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")` to avoid this?

Comment: what are you expecting if i enter `Deendayal      ` ? there are spaces after the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class nameinput {
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a name: (only letters, at least 2 characters long)");
        while (true) {
            String name= sc.nextLine();
            if (name.length() < 2){
                System.out.println("This name is too short!");
                continue;
            }
            else if (!name.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")){
                System.out.println("Letters only!");
                continue;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Hello, " + name);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```